# How to prevent stack-overflow from loop-references in gdb

Tags: c++, gdb

I have a list of `Foo`'s for which I also need (constant-time) random access, so I just created a vector to store the iterators to the list items. Note that the vector content does not need to be in the same order as the list. Though the `Foo`'s need to be aware of their location in the storage vector, so naturally each foo gets a `std::vector<std::list<Foo>::iterator>::iterator`. This means that there is a recursion, because from the original `Foo` you can go to it's iterator in the `std::vector<std::list<Foo>:iterator>` and from there you can again dereference this entry to go back to the original `Foo`. Now I don't know how to debug my program, because debugging and viewing a variable of type `Foo` in CLion (gdb) gives recursion errors, cf. my example below:

**Steps to reproduce**:

example.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

struct Foo {
  size_t index{}; // just to demonstrate the order inside the list
  std::vector<std::list<Foo>::iterator>::iterator storage_link{};

  Foo(size_t index_) : index{index_} {}
};

int main() {
  std::list<Foo> foos{};
  std::vector<std::list<Foo>::iterator> storage{};

  // populate the list with 2 entries
  foos.push_back(Foo{0});
  foos.push_back(Foo{1});

  // populate storage, order in storage vector may be arbitrary
  storage.push_back(std::prev(foos.end()));
  storage.push_back(foos.begin());

  // link list items to their storage iterator
  foos.begin()->storage_link = std::next(storage.begin());
  std::next(foos.begin())->storage_link = storage.begin();

  // get first and second item from the list through the storage
  auto second_foo{*storage.begin()};
  auto first_foo{*((*std::next(storage.begin()))->storage_link)};

  std::cout << "First storage item references Foo with index "
            << (*second_foo).index << "\n";
  std::cout << "Second storage item references Foo with index "
            << (*first_foo).index << "\n";

  return 0;
}
```

compile with

```
g++ -g -O0 -std=c++17 example.cpp -o example
```

and then debug with gdb and try to print the variable `second_foo`:

```
gdb ./example
(gdb) break /full/path/to/example.cpp:37
(gdb) run
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1459: file main.cpp, line 37.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /full/path/to/example
First storage item references Foo with index 1
Second storage item references Foo with index 0

Breakpoint 1, main () at example.cpp:37
37   return 0;
(gdb) p second_foo
$1 = Python Exception <class 'RecursionError'> maximum recursion depth exceeded while getting the str of an object: 

  {index = 1, storage_link = {index = 1, storage_link = {index = 1, storage_link = {index = 1, storage_link = {index......
```

The recursion of the last line goes on and on and I don't know how to tell gdb to ignore this.

Comment: What's your gdb version? I'm not getting this with 10.2. With 10.2 it prints about a hundred levels, before giving up and unwinding everything.

Comment: Basically there's no problem with cross-linked data structures (where you can go from A to B and vice versa). Looks like the problem is with the debugger only, and I don't understand why it tries to deref everything right away.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik My version is also 10.2 and yes it does print stuff, but ultimately throws an error, which also crashes the debugger in CLion.

Comment: My specific vesion is Fedora 34's gdb. Looks like Fedora might be including some patches in its gdb build, that addresses this problem.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a list of Foo's for which I also need (constant-time) random access, so I just created a vector to store the iterators to the list items.

Storing *iterators* in a container is almost never the right thing to do, and it very likely to cause subtle bugs.

If you need constant-time random access to `Foo`s, store *pointers* to them in the vector.

Comment: Why? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137116/storing-iterators-inside-containers says it's OK to store iterators iin a container.